# Dell Inspiron N5110 with Windows 7 Home Premium touchpad intermittently stops working

Tags: windows-7, touchpad, dell-inspiron

Sometimes the touchpad on my Dell Inspiron N5110 stops working and I need to restart the computer to get it to work again.  What should I do?

Comment: Your question was almost unreadable.  I've edited it for you, but please try to make your questions easier to read with better spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the driver that DELL has pre-installed and install the synaptics touchpad driver.  What you will get from that is a good response of the touchpad but without the features of the synaptics touchpad, for example scroll.

Answer (score 0):

[Try updating your Touchpad driver](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=TK588&FileId=2731101988&productCode=inspiron-15r-n5110&urlProductCode=False)

[Support page for your model,](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?) bookmark it for later reference